# Remove function using .this is not working

Tags: javascript

Here is the demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/8/) which I have created.

In that link, the "remove parent" is working. But, the "remove child" function is not working.

Here is the code I used:

```
$('.dec-child').on('click', function(){
    $(this.parent('.child:last').remove());
})
```

Comment: May be this fiddle will help http://jsfiddle.net/wpppLyek/

Comment: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/27/) is the correct answer, Everyone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not closed the `this` properly.

It should be

```
$(this).parent('.child:last').remove();
```

Also the selector is wrong.

With respect to the `.dec-child`, `.child` is a sibling and not a parent.

```
$(this).siblings('.child:last').remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yajuwizibe/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**

If you want to make it work for all dynamically added child elements then you must use event delegation.

```
$('body').on('click',".dec-child", function(){
        $(this).siblings('.child:last').remove();
  });
```

Comment: I tried closing it properly, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/8/). Still not working.

Comment: Here is a demo with dynamically created parent elements : http://jsbin.com/tigahafina/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: What should I do, Guys ??

You both are great programmers. I first accepted his answer only. Plz don't fight over this. Forgive me...

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code to

```
$('.dec-child').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.child:last').remove();
})
```

Above code will not work for you so try this and your code will work correctly.

Comment: Has issues while doing this on second parent. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/15/).

Comment: @ArunD you must use event delegation in that case. Because the button is added dynamically so it must use event delegation to listen to the event. Check my answer for a sample

Comment: Yes, If your creating buttons dynamicaly then you can't call click function of that button. So update your js file

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because `<div class="child"></div>` is not parent for `<a href="#" class="dec-child">remove previous Child</a>`, in our case you should use [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like so

```
$(document).on('click', '.dec-child', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.child:last').remove();
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/mrvtwpjp/26/)

If you use `parent()` you get `<div class="parent">`, so you need find in this div elements with class `.child`, you can do it like so

```
$(document).on('click', '.dec-child', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.child:last').remove();
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/mrvtwpjp/25/)

Comment: Works great, @Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

You should just wrap `this` with `jQuery` so it returns a jQuery object.

```
$('.dec-child').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('.child:last').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to

```
$('.dec-child').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.child').last().remove();
    })
```

please refer jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/22/